# Reference file relative to Jar deployment location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

How do I reference an external beans.xml file based on its relative location to where my jar file is deployed? This is what I have now, which doesn't work:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../beans.xml");
```

I want it out of the classpath so I can change things without redeploying, but relative to the deployed location of the jar so that it will work no matter where I put the jar and the beans.xml in the file system, as long as they are correctly situated relative to each other.

This is Spring btw, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to determine the file path of a JAR.  Your "System" file path will be relative to the application/jvm, but for JVMs it's usually the directory you start the application from.  Your best option would be to put your XML file in the classpath somewhere and load it that way, which is the most typical way I have seen it done.

Comment: Gotcha. Wont putting it in the classpath cause a problem, though, in that I wouldn't be able to edit the file without rebuilding?

Comment: The classpath doesn't have to be a JAR, it can be a directory.  For instance, in Tomcat, I believe you can put any file in the lib folder and it then becomes part of the classpath.

Comment: _but relative to the deployed location of the jar so that it will work no matter where I put the jar and the `beans.xml` in the file system_ This is the point of confusion. If your jar location changes, than the "relative to jar" statement fails. You can't make it work _no matter what_. You're better off deciding on a default place to put the `beans.xml` (ex: `/var/files/beans.xml`) file and use `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` to get it or add it to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application context file must be on the classpath to allow `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to work. To use a relative path you would have to use `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`.

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("../beans.xml");
```

Comment: How would I use a relative path with FileSystemXmlApplicationContext? How would I, for example, reference a file that was in the same directory as the deployed JAR?

Comment: The file location would be relative to the current working directory rather than the deployed JAR

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... but then again I don't think what I was looking for was possible. Ended up using this while passing in the path as an argument, allowing the beans.xml file to be placed anywhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can import the external beans configuration file in your `spring-config.xml` you can import the extends

```
<beans ...>
   <import resource="file:/path/to/external/config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

The above Spring config will import /path/to/external/config.xml. Having an external file will allow you to configure beans without having to rebuilding your main war/jar.

In your Java code, you can load it as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
```

and the `config.xml` file should be in:

```
project-classpath/config.xml
```

*More about loading external configuration files, you can find* [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/load-multiple-spring-bean-configuration-file/)